# Как закрыть/разорвать соединение вебсокет при определённом условии в ws.onmessage?

Tags: javascript, websocket

Добрый день. Столкнулся с проблемой - не могу закрыть вебсокет ws.close(); посылая с сервера например слово "close". В коде не все примеры моего маразма, но ни один не сработал.
Нужно в ws.onmessage при определённом условии if отключать соединение.

```
function create(url) {      
var flag = false;
        ws = new WebSocket(url);

        ws.onopen = function () {
            console.log('WebSocket opened ' );
        }
        ws.onmessage = function (e) {            
            if (e.data != 'close') { // тут может быть что угодно
               /********/
            } else {
                //ws.shutdownInput();
                //ws.shutdownOutput();
ws.close();
                my_close();                
                flag = true;
                return false;
            }
        }
        ws.onclose = function () {
            console.log('WebSocket closed');
            preloaderStart();            
        }
        function my_close() {            
            ws.close();
        }

        if(flag) ws.close();

        //ws.onerror = function () {run_server();}; // возможно перезагрузка страницы
    }
```

С сервера каждую секунду идут данные и нужно в какой-то момент перестать их получать совсем (имею ввиду консоль хрома network вкладка frames)

Comment: Вообще метод `close` должен закрыть сокет. Попробуйте вызвать `my_close` через `setTimeout`. Например `setTimeout(my_close,0)`.

Comment: странно но через setTimeout сработало, но мне нужно вызывать по приходу того или иного сообщения.

Comment: Используйте `setTimeout(my_close,0)` во время прихода сообщения.

Comment: не совсем так - если setTimeout в ws.onmessage то не работает, а если сразу под `function my_close() {            
            ws.close();
        }` то работает

Comment: Гммм... А вы удостоверьтесь, что `my_close` действительно вызывается. И попробуйте для таймаута задержку побольше поставить, например 200мс.

Comment: уверен так как в функцию добавил вывод в консоль и получается что в ws.onmessage хоть 10000 в setTimeout ставлю то всё равно при условии из if начинает отрабатывать каждую секунду (ws.onmessage срабатывает каждую секунду) с ошибкой Uncaught TypeError: ws.close is not a function
    at my_close

Comment: вопрос решен var ws = new WebSocket(url);

Comment: Хе-хе, вот и решилась проблема... Ошибку надо было сразу в вопрос добавить, за минуту бы решили. Кстати, а в приведенном ваме примере кода в вопросе - ошибки то нету!

Answer (score 1):

Переменная объявлялась за функцией и поэтому не была видна
    var ws = new WebSocket(url);